# If the Jacobian is the first derivative, the Hessian is the second derivative, what is the third derivative called?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, terminology, matrix-calculus

I'm wondering about the following: If the Jacobian is the first derivative, the Hessian is the second derivative, what is the third derivative called?

Comment: The Jacobian is the 1st derivative of a *vector* field. The Hessian is the 2nd derivative of a *scalar* field.

Comment: The gradient is the first derivative of a scalar field, and $\nabla f(x)$ can be viewed as a linear functional. The Hessian is the second derivative of a scalar field and $\nabla^2 f(x)$  can be viewed as a bilinear form. $f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x) + \nabla f(x)(\Delta x) + \frac12 \nabla^2 f(x)(\Delta x, \Delta x)$. Continuing this pattern, the third derivative should be a trilinear form and we should have the approximation $f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x) + \nabla f(x)(\Delta x) + \frac12 \nabla^2 f(x)(\Delta x, \Delta x) + \frac{1}{3!} \nabla^3 f(x)(\Delta x,\Delta x,\Delta x)$.

Comment: Interesting. What's the significance of the third derivative? People always argue that the second derivative gives us curvature information